Import ERROR but I've installed PYGRAPHVIZ 1.12
The question is......
C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py:433: UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored
node_collection = ax.scatter(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 295, in pygraphviz_layout
import pygraphviz
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz_init_.py", line 24, in 
from .agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute, DotError
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 15, in 
from . import graphviz as gv
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\graphviz.py", line 10, in 
from . import _graphviz
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _graphviz: 找不到指定的模块。
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Code\Python\Map\t.py", line 191, in 
pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog="neato")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 251, in graphviz_layout
return pygraphviz_layout(G, prog=prog, root=root, args=args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\26913\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", line 297, in pygraphviz_layout
raise ImportError(
ImportError: requires pygraphviz http://pygraphviz.github.io/
I've installed Graphviz and added it to the path.
